# Jquery touch event apply is not a function

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla donde arrastro y suelto filas (drag and drop). Para poder arrastrar y soltar, y también desplazar la página (sin arrastrar y soltar), aplico Jquery Touch.

El problema es cuando hago `tap` o `doubletap` en la tabla me muestra un error en la consola.

Este es el error

```
jquery.js:4737 Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function
at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
at triggerCustomEvent (jquery.mobile-events.js:846)
at HTMLTableElement.tapFunc2 (jquery.mobile-events.js:498)
at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
at HTMLTableElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
```

Y esta es la función

```
$('.touchtable').tap('tap', function(e) { 
  console.log('hola2');
});
```

La información que he mirado es la siguiente:

https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events#4-the-events

Alguna manera de corregir el error?

Comment: Estás usando jQuery mobile o jQuery? Si la librería que usas en tu aplicación no es jQuery Mobile el comportamiento no será el mismo.

Comment: Utilizo Jquery, así que borrare el primer enlace que he puesto. Aun así el segundo es un enlace a una extensión de Jquery, que es la que he utilizado para el ejemplo, esa función estaría correcta? @PabloLozano

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que defines la función jquery `.tap()` y dentro declaras el tipo de evento tap, pero eso no existe como tal. Primero tendrías que declarar el `.on()` y dentro declarar el tap. Por si no me has entendido te dejo el codigo js:

```
$('.touchtable').on('tap', function(e) { 
  console.log('hola');
});
$('.touchtable').on('doubletap', function(e) { 
  console.log('hola');
});
```

Comment: Gracias Marc, funciona en pc pero no en móvil, me sale el error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.ui.mouse')`

Answer (score 0):

El codigo debe ser así:

```
    $('.touchtable').on('doubletap', function(e) { 
        console.log('User tapped touchtable'); 
    });
```